# Simple MIPS Assembly

Tags: assembly, mips

I can't quite figure out what I'm doing wrong in my assembly code. I'm trying to write a program that compares two null terminated strings that are inputted  as $a0, and $a1 sometime during the "main:" section and then calls

```
jal hamming
```

to start the program.

Basically for this section I want two strings to be compared char by char until one string hits the null terminating char. Then the program stops and returns how many chars were different until termination.

I think it has to do with the jumps that I am using, but I'm not quite sure. The program is sort of long so I took the main piece that I think is the problem (hence ignore variables like $a3, that has been initialized and defined already):

```
diffchar:
        li $t4, 0
        li $t5, 1

        beq $a0, $a1, samechars
        move $v0, $t5
        j diffcharend

samechars:
        move $v0, $t4

diffcharend:
        jr $ra

hamming:

absvaluedone:
        li $a2, 0
        #li $v0, 0

        move $t0, $a0
        move $t1, $a1

hammingloopbegin:
        lb $t2, 0($t0)
        lb $t3, 0($t1)
        beq $t2, $0, hammingdone
        beq $t3, $0, hammingdone

        la $a0, 0($t0)
        la $a1, 0($t1)
        jal diffchar **#this is the line that causes me problems, if I take this out it is fine**
        beq $v0, $0, next
        addiu $a2, $a2, 1

next:
        addiu $t0, $t0, 1
        addiu $t1, $t1, 1
        j hammingloopbegin

hammingdone:
        add $v0, $a2, $a3
        jr $ra
```

When I run my program my output looks like an infinite loop that keeps saying:

```
Exception occurred at PC=0x00400144
  Bad address in data/stack read: 0x10021226
  Exception 7  [Bad address in data/stack read]  occurred and ignored
Exception occurred at PC=0x00400140
  Bad address in data/stack read: 0x1002121b
  Exception 7  [Bad address in data/stack read]  occurred and ignored
```

I think there's something wrong with diffchar or the process I use to jump around to diffchar. This is my first time writing assembly code so I think theres something really basic I am missing thats making this mess up. Any pointers would be great.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not save the return address before `jal diffchar`. It returns and `$ra` still holds the new value. When you `jr $ra` again in `hammingdone`, you jump back to right after the `diffchar` call. You need to store `$ra` somewhere before calling `diffchar` and restore it after the call returns.

Here is a [good explanation of nested procedures in MIPS](http://www.cs.uaf.edu/~cs301/notes/Chapter9/node5.html), which describes the problem you are experiencing and a solution using the runtime stack:

> When the `jal B` instruction is executed, the return address in register
>   `$ra` for procedure A will be overwritten with the return address for
>   procedure B. Procedure B will return correctly to A, but when
>   procedure A executes the `jr` instruction, it will return again to the
>   return address for B, which is the next instruction after `jal B` in
>   procedure A. This puts procedure A in an infinite loop.
>
> ...
>
> The system stack is commonly used to save return addresses. They can
>   be pushed on the stack when a procedure is called and popped off to
>   execute a return instruction.
>
> A return address in register `$ra` can be pushed onto the system stack
>   with the following MAL code:
>
> ```
>     sw      $ra, ($sp)
>     add     $sp, -4
> ```
>
> The following code pops a return address from the top of the stack and
>   returns it in register `$ra`:
>
> ```
>     add     $sp, 4
>     lw      $ra, ($sp)
> ```